# Dual monitors with two Nvidia GPU's

Tags: nvidia, screen, monitor

I have two gtx 275s SLI'd, When I connect both monitors to same card it allows me to enable twinview, and it works. But when I want to connect each monitor to different cards, I lose the option of twinview and my secondary screen is just white and when i mouse over it my mouse turns into an X.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.33  (buildd@allspice)  Fri Mar 30 13:37:33 UTC 2012

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics M2762D"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL E193FP"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    # generated from default
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1280 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 275"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 275"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection
```

Comment: just out of interest why do you want to connect them to different cards? AFAIK the computing power of the cards is shared over the two cards through SLI so it doesn't matter which you plug into

Comment: In theory that's true, but in Windows I have noticed a performance increase when using one monitor per GPU, but that may be due to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at chapter 29 of the documentation for the proprietary nvidia drivers. For only two displays nvidia seems to recommend using twinview with both displays connected to one card as this configuration seems to give you the best experience.

You can find the documentation when selecting to download the Linux driver from the official site. It is the README link in the additional information tab.

Or use the Unix related page instead and be sure to use the documentation that matches your driver version and architecture:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html