# Is it possible to use both SLI and two monitors at the same time on Ubuntu with Nvidia?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, performance

I'm completely and utterly baffled by my inability to use both SLI and a dual monitor setup, even with Nvidia's latest proprietary drivers.

Now I have to choose between the ergonomic and productive use of more than one monitor or sufficient performance for my games.

I could reboot between both settings but I may as well boot into Windows then for gaming.

Just to make clear: I'm having absolutely **no problems** enabling **SLI on its own** or setting up both monitors perfectly **on their own** - I know where these options are and how to use them. I'm just completely unable to use them **both at the same time!**

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Comment: Maybe this will help --> [Dual monitors with two Nvidia GPU's](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135470/dual-monitors-with-two-nvidia-gpus) or this --> [Nvidia SLI and dual monitor](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1115999)

Comment: You may wish to look at visualization possibilities instead of rebooting on another OS each time.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 14.04 and the latest Nvidia drivers?

Comment: FWIW: ppa:xorg-edgers seems to be hassle free. `dpkg --list | grep nvidia` might reveal more than "just what you need". It might be a good idea to clean up anything that doesn't need to be there (e.g: nvidia-337 and nvidia-settings for xorg-edgers). I'm on 14.04 LTS/64b with a single GTX 780 if that matters.

Comment: SLI stands for Scan Line Interleaving. So basically it will let you leverage the power of multiple GPUs in one screen. With multiple screens the need for SLI will disapear, unless you want your GPU bound application to show one window accross all screens (that will then need to be exactly same height).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help, I'm using nvidia both at home and at work.

In the one machine I have a GX550 Ti (home) and in the other 2 Quatro 2000 cards. On both machines I have 3 monitors connected.

To make this work I had to configure each monitor on there own xserver.

1. In Nvidia X Server Settings → X Server Display Configuration: select the monitor which is disabled or hidden behind the other monitor.
2. In the Configuration pull down menu add new xserver. Also enable the Xinerama check box.
3. Drag the screen to fit your need.
4. The next is important: Click Save to X Configuration File and save the configuration in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

You will have to restart the Display Manager or reboot your computer.

If any thing goes wrong you can always delete the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot.

Some times (not very often) have I problems with the display configuration. Then the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file is renamed by system to something like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.062914`. To fix it just copy: `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.062914 /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot

You will often see application complain about XRAND is missing but it will not give any problems. Some standard display configuration apps will not work and you will have to use NVidia Settings.

Hopes this solves your problem.